# LOOKUP and REFERENCE Function - Cannot get either to work - merging tables

Tags: dax, lookup, powerbi-desktop

I have numerous tables that I want to combine into one single table and build my dashboard from there. I am trying to do this with LOOKUPVALUE because I cannot get the relationships working correctly, otherwise I would be trying RELATED().

I want to fill in the values of **Data[NEW]** by looking up **Data[Issue Key]** in **Sprint Name[Issue Key]** and returning the corresponding value of **Sprint Name[Sprint Name]**

[image]

So far, I have

```
LOOKUPVALUE('Sprint Name'[Issue Key],'Sprint Name'[Issue Key],Data[Issue Key])
```

With this, I am getting the **Issue Key** values in the **New** column, but I want the **Sprint Name**. I have tried different combinations but still cannot get it to work, I either get a blank column or an error message.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Result =
LOOKUPVALUE (
    'Sprint Name'[Sprint Name],
    'Sprint Name'[Issue Key], Data[Issue Key]
)
```